# python 2.x wikipedia parsing

Tags: python, parsing, csv, wikipedia, pywikibot

I have this code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url='https://en.wikipedia.org'
start_url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming'
outfile_name='Computer_programming.csv'
no_of_links=10

fp=open(outfile_name, 'wb')

def get_links(link):
    html = urllib.urlopen(link).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    ret_list=soup.select('p a[href]')
    count=0
    ret=[]
    for tag in ret_list:
        link=tag['href']
        if link[0]=='/' and ':' not in link and link[:5]=='/wiki' and '#' not in link:
            ret.append(base_url+link)
            count=count+1
        if count==no_of_links:
            return ret

l1=get_links(start_url)
for link in l1:
    fp.write('%s;%s\n'%(start_url,link))

for link1 in l1:
    l2=get_links(link1)
    for link in l2:
        fp.write('%s;%s\n'%(link1,link))

    for link2 in l2:
        l3=get_links(link2)
        for link in l3:
            fp.write('%s;%s\n'%(link2,link))

fp.close()
```

is saves an neighborhood of nodes in an csv file.
But when I try to run it I'm getting this error:

```
for link in l3:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I get the same error when I trying to run the code for another Wikipedia link, like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology.
The only page on which it works is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science. And that's a problem since I need to collect the data on more sites not only the Computer science one.

Can anyone give me a hint how to deal with it??

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should debug your program line-by-line. It seems that at some moment in function get_links occurs count != no_of_links, so function returns None.

Comment: the empty links should be skipped, not make the program stop, that's the problem

Comment: And what if there is less than 10 links on a page? Try returning ret at the end of the function.

Comment: Why do you loop over the links twice? `for link in l1:` and `for link1 in l1:`? You could just combine those loops

Comment: Also, it looks like you're doing breadth first search. I would recommend a recursive function with a depth limit instead of nesting sequences of for loops

Comment: I always like to code in small segments to make sure everything works before writing 100 lines and then trying to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Parsing HTML is rarely the best approach for anything. Try using the [links API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Links) ([example](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Computer%20programming&prop=links&pllimit=500)).

Answer (score 0):

If `ret_list` is empty, or if there are fewer links than requested,  the code takes a branch without any explicit `return` statement, and therefore implicitly returns `None` when it falls off at the end of the function.

Without going into other problems with this code, you probably want something like this instead:

```
def get_links(link):
    html = urllib.urlopen(link).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    ret_list=soup.select('p a[href]')
    count=0
    ret=[]
    for tag in ret_list:
        link=tag['href']
        if link[0]=='/' and ':' not in link and link[:5]=='/wiki' and '#' not in link:
            ret.append(base_url+link)
            count=count+1
        if count==no_of_links:
            break
    return ret
```